# Installing Zlib for PHP on Windows

Tags: php, wamp

How do I install Zlib for PHP under Windows?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php

Comment: Yes, I read this, but I am essentially asking what "You will need to configure PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]" means and how it's done.

Comment: @moteutsch that part relates to building/compiling PHP from scratch only. If you are using the Windows binaries, there is nothing to do.

Comment: So there is no way for me to install Zlib?

Comment: @moteutsch: Apparently you have **not** read that, otherwise you would have seen the *huge* box saying "Note: Built-in support for zlib on Windows is available with PHP 4.3.0." It could have been formulated "4.3.0 and newer", but aside from that, I don't see how it doesn't answer your question. [spoonfeeding]If you use PHP 4.3.0 or newer (this includes PHP 5) on Windows, zlib is already installed and you don't need to install it.[/spoonfeeding] Happy now?

Comment: I don't understand the fact that, regardless of what it says, I don't have Zlib installed. I cannot find its dll, there is no trace of it in php.ini and when I try using its functions I get "no such function exists" type errors.

Comment: @moteutsch: Aha! *Now* that's a different question. If you run `phpinfo()`, is there any mention of it?

Comment: Yes: http://pastebin.com/qPby9671

Answer (score 0):

Since it is included in PHP versions since 4.3.0, I would put a phpinfo.php page online with the following contents:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Save this file, upload it to a web-accessible directory and browse to it. I would then do a find (Ctrl+F in Firefox) and search for zlib. That'll show you information regarding zlib if it is detected - It should be.

Once you have your information, I would delete the phpinfo.php file from the server or at least move it out of the web-accessible directory to prevent snooping.